# HERE Maps TextAutoSuggestion gives BAD_REQUEST

Tags: android, here-api

```
@Override
public void onSearchTextChanged(String oldQuery, final String newQuery) {

    if (!oldQuery.equals("") && newQuery.equals("")) {
     m_searchView.clearSuggestions();
    } else {

     textAutoSuggestionRequest = new TextAutoSuggestionRequest(newQuery);

     textAutoSuggestionRequest.execute(new ResultListener < List < AutoSuggest >> () {

       @Override
       public void onCompleted(List < AutoSuggest > autoSuggests, ErrorCode error) {
        if (error == ErrorCode.NONE) {
         if (autoSuggests.size() > 0) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "kek", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //searchlist = autoSuggests;
          for (int i = 0; i < autoSuggests.size(); i++) {
           //                                        listItems.add(autoSuggests.get(i).getTitle());
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), autoSuggests.get(i).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
         } else {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Displays as BAD_REQUEST
         }
        }
       });



     }

     //Log.d(TAG, "onSearchTextChanged()");
    }
    });
}
```

As seen in the code above, it does not go into the if (error == ErrorCode.NONE) block since the error is BAD_REQUEST as seen in the Toast. I have tried with my Wifi and Mobile Data and with different networks but to no avail. Any suggestions on how to solve the error?

Edit: Also I am using https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview as my searchbar hence the method onSearchTextChanged is derived from there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue may be that you are not setting a location context for the request. You can do this using either `TextAutoSuggestionRequest#setSearchCenter(GeoCoordinate center)` or `TextAutoSuggestionRequest#setMapViewport(GeoBoundingBox mapViewport)`.

- See also: [TextAutoSuggestionRequest User Guide](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/places.html#places__search-request-autosuggestion), [TextAutoSuggestionRequest API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-search-textautosuggestionrequest.html)

Comment: I keep getting a fatal exception on async task - java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground(). The code in the example in the official documentation link does not seem to help in my case. I would like to pass a partial string query and receive a list of suggestions. How do I tweak the example in doing so? @AndrewJC